# JAX-RS ExceptionMapper does not work for any Exception other than java.lang.Exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, jax-rs, exceptionmapper

I am using spring boot along with JAX-RS and Jersey.
I have defined different kinds of `ExceptionMappers` for different types of `Exceptions` and one `ExceptionMapper` as the `Fallback` mapper just to log the exception properly and send back the correct response to clients. On unit test level everything works fine and the the proper `ExceptionMapper` is called for its corresponding `Exception` using the

```
<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-inmemory</artifactId>
```

However on the running application (embedded in Jetty) only the Fallback mapper which catches the `java.lang.Exception` is called and all others are ignored. I am using annotation scanning for everything and the `FallbackExceptionMapper` and `MyCustomExceptionMapper` are both in the same package and annotated with `@Provider`. Any idea why other exception mappers like `MyCustomExceptionMapper` do not work?

**Update:** I changed the type of the Exception from `java.lang.Exception` in my `FallbackExceptionMapper` to `MyCustomException` and this also is not called. Seems like that no other Exception other than the root Exception (`java.lang`) is caught by the mapper.

**Update2:** by defining the `@Context javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers` providers in my FallbackExceptionMapper and the method `providers.getExceptionMapper(MyCustomException.class)` I do see that it returns an instance of MyCustomExceptionMapper but I'm wondering why Jersey does not call it! Any idea??

Comment: I imagine it has to do with where the exception is being thrown. Have to tested with throwing from different locations. If it works being thrown from different locations, then let us know the location it's being thrown from, and the response you are getting.

Comment: @peeskillet actually I found out last night that the exceptions are caught by my mapper and it is working but it does not work in this case because Spring swallows my exception and throws it's own exception because of the rollback and this is the reason why my fallback catches them. I made another post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33881648/springs-transactioninterceptor-overrides-my-exception