# Spring's TransactionInterceptor overrides my Exception

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

I have a DAO class catching the `javax.persistence.PersistenceException` wrapping them and rethrowing it as a checked exception. This method is marked as `@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`.

If I get an exception in my DAO like constraint violation it will be wrapped in my custom Exception, however spring overrides my exception

```
[tp1415357209-22] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Application exception overridden by commit exception
```

and throws it's own `org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly`

"swallowing" my exception by just logging it and rethrowing its own exception. How can I prevent spring from doing this?

P.S.

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor = { MyCustomException.class})
```

does not work. Of course I do want the transaction to set as rollback but I don't want my exception being swallowed by spring.

Comment: One option is you catch TransactionSystemException and use its getOriginalException() to get your PersistenceException object back.

Comment: @mohit This is not what I want and actually breaks the contract of my interface to upper levels. I want to wrap any exception from underlying layers to my own  exceptions and only throw those exceptions to upper layers I just don't understand why spring does something like this. Nothing like this happens with JEE or I assume that there is a way for this also in Spring telling it not to swallow my exception.

Comment: Which spring version are you using?

Answer (score 10):

The solution was to use `rollbackFor` instead of the other attribute so that spring doesn't swallow my own exception

Answer (score 3):

In case you have a few different Checked Exceptions that you can raise in your class or method, you can use the generic Exception class as well

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

Example in Kotlin:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = [MagicNotAvailableException::class])
@Throws(MagicNotAvailableException::class)
fun doMagicOrThrow()
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the curly braces `rollbackFor` to be like this

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = MyCustomExc.class)
```